# How do I get the url of an image I uploaded?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a profile picture, and I am choosing a photo from my gallery. I want to upload the url to parse. Am I doing it correctly? I always get a nil for the url.

```
var fileurl = PFFile(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 1.0)!)
print(NSURL(string: (fileurl?.url)!))
```

Comment: Don't force unwrap (exclamation mark). I don't know parse.com, so not sure how much I can help you, but what does the PFFile() function return?

Comment: It just returns a PFFile. I am converting the image to a PFFile, parse's version to store files

Comment: When do you upload it?

Comment: Later on, but that is not important. I just need to print the url

Comment: But how should it have an url if you haven't uploaded it yet? (Or is it not an internet address?). Besides that, if you place a breakpoint on the first line and step over it you should be able to see all members of fileurl, no need to print it.

Comment: Yes that is true. I do need to upload it to parse, then return the url which I am unsure on how to do

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. If you are getting the image from your phone and want its storage position this is the location.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage?, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

        if let imageURL = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
            //imageURL if the full path

            let imageName = imageURL.lastPathComponent!
            //imageName is the name and extension of the file
        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP's trying to do. I think OP wants the url of the image after upload.

Comment: "I want to upload the url to parse" That sounds like something he has before he stores the photo to me.